# Mustache Error {}

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js, mustache

So I have a mustache template which contains this:

```
{{#data}}
<tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
</tr>
{{/data}}
```

This is what I am doing:

```
try {
    var view = {
        "data": data
    };
    console.log(data);
    $("#containter").html(Mustache.render(template, view));
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

And I am getting this error in the console:

```
Error {}
```

I can see the data logged in the console and it's array of objects:

```
[Object, Object]
```

so it should work.

Each object in an array is a proper object created from a constructor, like:

```
var Foo = function () {
    this.foo = function () {

    };
}

var obj = new Foo();
obj.hello = world;

data.push(obj);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? The error from Mustache is not descriptive at all... :(

EDIT, btw I tried to use Handlebars instead of Mustache and I got ReferenceError {} instead. Again no clear explanation of what's wrong.

Comment: @RichardKnop - here's a close approximation fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcw0933/jJ7Pt/  Try playing with that to see what's breaking?

Comment: Does this still happen if you replace your **data** for just a simple string? Also, this functionality has 2 purposes in Mustache. It can be used to check if the variable exists, but also as a for loop.